# Having Problem after installing Ubuntu

Tags: lts, versions

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu LTS on my machine which is Dell N5010 after a while Ubuntu started  bothering me by freezing, crash out and so on now here is my question, assuming that I'm fresh in Ubuntu wich Version of that is more stable and reliable?
Machine hardware details:
Intel core i5,
8 GB RAM  4*2 (upgraded, default 2*2),
Graphic Adaptor 1G ATI,
HDD 500GB.
Thank you,
Mojtaba

Comment: Normally, Ubuntu is very stable. Maybe it has some problems with your hardware, maybe another version won''t help you. Could you please edit your question and give us some details on your hardware?

Comment: @RoVo Thank you for your response i had same thought when i faced with the problem for the first time but should be mentioned i don't have this problem with windows! By the way i will add the hardware details.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h`. Report back to @heynnema